# How can I use my controller to play Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

The controller I'm using is Universal USB 2.0 Wireless Vibration Controller Gamepad Joypad for PC, EW800. I plugged in the usb and the computer is detecting the controller. However, I'm unable to use it to play Borderlands 2. Help?

Answer (score 1):

3rd party controllers (IE: Not Microsoft's xbox controllers) often do not work very well with PC games without unofficial software, as the PC often doesn't detect the controller as an Xbox controller, while games like Borderlands will work perfectly fine from the start with an Xbox controller without tinkering. To fix this, you could:

- Buy An Xbox Controller/Steam Controller (not ideal)
- Use a program like MotionJoy (MotionInjoy?) or JoyToKey to recognize your controller and map the buttons to controls in borderlands 2.

Comment: JoyToKey maps XInput button presses and analog stick movements to keypresses and mouse movements/clicks, so it's far from ideal. MotionInJoy is no longer supported by the developer(s), and is bloated adware anyway. [ScpToolkit](https://github.com/nefarius/ScpToolkit) is a much better solution.

Comment: Might try that myself, little projects like this often go under my radar, but that looks like a good solution. Doesn't DS4 have default drivers now though? Or very soon?

Comment: I wouldn't know. I don't own a DS4 controller - just some Xbox 360 and One controllers, and various generics.

Comment: Sony are releasing a Wireless dongle for DS4, working with PSNow and maybe other games. Just for anyone interested - https://www.destructoid.com/the-dualshock-4-pc-wireless-adapter-is-up-for-order-on-amazon-382408.phtml